# How to solve A*x=B in GAP (A,B are matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, gap

Solving $A x = b$ with matrix $A$ and vector $b$ can be done in GAP using SolutionMat.
How would you find the solution to $A x =B$ with $B$ a matrix? Are there simplifications
if I only need to know whether the solution exists or not (rather than getting the actual
solution)?

Comment: Ummm... what is GAP?

Comment: See [this](https://www.gap-system.org/), @DavidG.Stork.

Comment: So is this a question about *mathematics* or instead *software*?

Comment: Depending on the size of $B$, this problem can be reduced to solving many linear systems $Ax=b_j$, where $b_j$ is column j of the matrix $B$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This is a question about both. I suspect the answer is simple (creating an augmented matrix $(A|B)$ and calculating rank, but there could be subtleties that I've overlooked. Someone more knowledgeable in GAP or linear algebra can help clear things up; this should also be a problem of interest for others...

Comment: Is $x$ a matrix in $Ax=B$?

Comment: Note that GAP solves $xA=b$ (since action is always from the right). Yopu'll need to transpose to solve the other way around.

Comment: $B$ will have the same number of columns as $x$. If $x$ is a column vector, so is $B$.

Comment: @ahulpke you're right. So would the solution be applying "SolutionMat" to the columns of $B$ one at a time? (Sean Roberson's comment)

Comment: @unknown  If you solve it in GAP, you transpose, getting $x^TA^T=B^T$. And now you  solve for  the rows of $x^T$ from the rows of $B^T$. That is, the columns of $x$ come from `SolutionMat(TransposedMat(A),c)` with `c` going through the columns of $B$.